# How to create instances of S4 classes from R packages in Rcpp code

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm getting my feet wet with Rcpp trying to create an instance of a sparseMatrix from within Rcpp code.

I understand that in order to create S4 objects we call the S4 constructor with the name of the desired class as a string, e.g.:

```
S4 foo() {
    S4 s("dgCMatrix");
    return s;
}
```

But in my case this fails with

```
Error in getClass("dgCMatrix") : “dgCMatrix” is not a defined class
```

I assume this is because the Matrix package has not been loaded? I have tried adding

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(Matrix)]]
```

as well as Imports and LinkingTo directives for Matrix in the package's DESCRIPTION, but I still get the same error. How can one create instances from R classes from within Rcpp?

UPDATE: following [coatless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345455/coatless)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572422/1386105%20answer), classes need to be imported in the namespace if Matrix is not to be loaded:

```
//' @importClassesFrom Matrix dgCMatrix
// [[Rcpp::export]]
S4 foo() {
    S4 s("dgCMatrix");
    return s;
}
```

Takes care of it in case you are using Roxygen2 to manage the namespace.

Comment: Huh? What is this expression supposed to represent: `S4 s("dgCMatrix")`   ... need more code.

Comment: You don't call the constructor function `Matrix` there. Either call this R function from Rcpp or create your own constructor in C++. Or use a sparse matrix class from Armadillo.

Comment: There _are_ examples for this out there _e.g._ on the [Rcpp Gallerty](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: @42- it's supposed to be a c++ constructor.

Comment: @Roland I don't understand. What constructor? You mean the R one? You 
 mean call the R constructor as a Function object from within C++? I'm lifting that line of code directly from the example provided here: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/as-and-wrap-for-sparse-matrices/

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I know! I looked at many many examples, but most of them use inline, precede calls to the Rcpp function at runtime with either library(Matrix) or setClass for the desired S4 class, etc. I actually took the idea of creating S4 with the string constructor from the example posted in the Rcpp gallery here: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/as-and-wrap-for-sparse-matrices/ but if there's a better one, I would appreciate it if you could link to it. Or even maybe paste it as an _answer_? thanks!

Comment: @Roland thank you for the snarky pedantic comment. Just what I needed. In that example, the return object is being created as an S4 instance with a std::string parameter. How is that different to (the moronically obviously incomplete example of) what I'm doing? The example does not provide context for how you accomplish S4 creation from within a package using a class from a dependency. Do I need to manually load Matrix at runtime? I thought that was what Rcpp::depends, Imports and LinkingTo were for, but that still fails.

Comment: Yes, you need to load Matrix in R or import it if you are building a package. No, this doesn't belong in Rcpp::depends (at least that's my understanding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you are running into is the `Matrix` package has not been loaded. So, when *Rcpp* searches for the *dgCMatrix* ctor it comes up empty and, thus, triggering the error you see. To get around this, you can simply load the `Matrix` library once at the start of every session. e.g.

```
library("Matrix")
sourceCpp("path/to/S4_declaration.cpp")
```

Alternatively, you could add a load call in the `sourceCpp` compile you are performing. This is a bit more extreme as you only need to load the library once.

Though, the following should always work under `sourceCpp()`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::S4 make_dgCMatrix() {
  Rcpp::S4 s("dgCMatrix");
  return s;
}


/*** R
library("Matrix")
make_dgCMatrix()
*/
```

When you move this into an R package, make sure you import the `Matrix` package in the `DESCRIPTION`

```
Imports:
    Matrix
```

and import `dgCMatrix` definition in `NAMESPACE`.

```
importClassesFrom(Matrix, dgCMatrix)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, I figured it out literally two minutes ago :). I ended up using the importClassesFrom( Matrix, dgTMatrix ) directive; I understand importFrom imports _functions_, while importClassesFrom imports S4 classes. In any case, I'm managing my NAMESPACE with roxygen2, so the precise modification was to add '//' @importClassesFrom Matrix dgTMatrix' to the c++ function header, inmediately above the Rcpp::export attribute. Also, I don't think the ***R part is really necessary, as long as you make sure to importClassesFrom in the NAMESPACE.

Comment: Whooops. Thanks for catching the import directive snafu. I've updated the answer.