# calling nested R functions and packages in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I prepared one R function ,say "rtap" which uses "state" library and some function in this library. Also, I have one Rcpp function which calls the "rtap". 
My R function works in R but not in Rcpp. It is my R function:

```
 rtap<-function(series,max.lag=NULL,max.dep=NULL){
        #parameters
        n<-length(series)
        x<-0:(n-1)
        minVal<-Inf
        iPos<-0

        #kernel
        kern<-function(sigma,d){exp(-d/sigma)}

        #K: maximal relevant lag
        if(is.null(max.lag)){
            K<-max(min(round((10*log(10*n))),ceiling(sqrt(n))),30)
        }else{
            K<-min(n-1,max.lag)}
        lags<-(1:K)
        corr<-acf(series,lag=K,plot=FALSE,type="covariance")$acf
        R0.hat<-toeplitz(c(corr))

        #b: length of data window
        if(is.null(max.dep)){
            b<-round(max(K*4/3,round(n^(1/3))))
        }else{
            b<-max(max.dep,K*4/3) }    

        #R0.hat regularization
        for(l in 1:length(lags)){
            Sum<-0
            reg<-kern(lags[l],x[1:(K+1)])
            for(nu in 1:(n-b+1)){
                series.c<-series[nu:(nu+b-1)]
                corr.c<-acf(series.c,lag=K,plot=FALSE,type="covariance")$acf
                R0.c<-toeplitz(c(corr.c)*reg)
                Sum<-Sum+max(rowSums(abs(R0.c-R0.hat))) }
            Sum<-Sum/(n-b+1)
            if(Sum<minVal){
                minVal<-Sum
                iPos<-l
            }
        }
        corr<-c(acf(series,lag=n-1,plot=FALSE)$acf)*kern(lags[iPos],x)

        #return
        list(acf=corr,error=minVal,lag=lags[iPos],R.hat=toeplitz(corr))
    }
```

And my Rcpp code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat f(arma::vec ve){
  using namespace std;
  using namespace arma;

Rcpp::Environment myEnv = Rcpp::Environment::global_env();
Rcpp::Environment Matrix("package:Matrix"); 
Rcpp::Environment stats("package:stats"); 
Rcpp::Function toeplitz = stats["toeplitz"];  
Rcpp::Function acf = stats["acf"];   
Rcpp::Function rtap = myEnv["rtrap"];

Rcpp::List rtapp = rtap(ve);
mat Rhat= rtapp["R.hat"];
return Rhat;
}
```

When I Run my Rcpp Function, I receive this error message"

```
Error in f(vec) : cannot convert to function
```

I don't know why it happens.I have defined all of the related environments and functions. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks beforehands

Comment: Please upgrade to Rcpp 0.12.11. Secondly, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560198/how-to-create-instances-of-s4-classes-from-r-packages-in-rcpp-code . In essence, the function/package is not _loaded_ prior to call.

Comment: @coatless Thanks for your comment, I checked it. But the code doesn't work yet and returns the similar error message as before.